# Psycopg2 Json UTF8

Tags: python, json, postgresql, utf-8, psycopg2

In Postgres I have column of json type with UTF-8 encoding. I am inserting json from Python with Psycopg2

`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table (json_data) VALUES (%s)",Json(data))`

The result in the database is

`{"item": "r\u00f6b"}`

Meaning ö appears as \u00f6. When I manually insert this item through pgAdmin, it appears normally as ö. The documentation says that psycopg2.extras.Json uses dumps inside, which has this encoding issue. Could you suggest a solution to this to allow storing `{"item": "röb"}` without \u ?

Comment: FYI, a quick check found that the types `json` and `jsonb` differ in their behavior in this regard. Where  `ö` is not escaped in `jsonb`  and is in `json` when entered via `psycopg2`. This is sort of explained here [JSON types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html). I don't have time at the moment to update the question with example, but will when I get the chance.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have set column to ```jsonb``` and the code with basic ```Json ``` started to work properly, no escaping. I've also verified the answer with the custom lambda, which also worked perfectly, and ```jsonb``` seems to be preferred, as ```jsonb``` allows indexing as well (and it is still human readable in pgAdmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to `json.dumps` having the default of `ensure_ascii=True` per [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json):

> If ensure_ascii is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If ensure_ascii is false, these characters will be output as-is.
> ...

> As permitted, though not required, by the RFC, this module’s serializer sets ensure_ascii=True by default, thus escaping the output so that the resulting strings only contain ASCII characters.

The solution is to override the default by creating a lambda function that uses `dumps(ensure_ascii=False)`. Derived from examples here [psycopg2 json](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json).

```
import json
from psycopg2.extras import Json 

json.dumps('ö')                                                                                                                                                            
'"\\u00f6"'

json.dumps('ö', ensure_ascii=False)                                                                                                                                        
'"ö"'

dumps_lambda = lambda x: json.dumps(x, ensure_ascii=False)

j = Json('ö', dumps=dumps_lambda)                                                                                                                                         

j.adapted                                                                                                                                                                 
'ö'
```

Comment: Verified, it works properly. Thanks a lot!